# Error: (0 , react_intersection_observer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useInView) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I was using Next 14 Server Side App, when I got the following error.
`Error: (0 , react_intersection_observer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useInView) is not a function`

How do I solve this? I have added the code below.

`

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useInView} from "react-intersection-observer";

function LoadMore() {
    const {ref, inView } = useInView();

return ( 
   <>
    <section className = "flex justify-centre items-centre w-full">
    <div >
    <Image src = "./spinner.svg" alt = "spinner"
    width = {56}
    height = {56}
    className = "object-contain" 
    />
    </div> 
   </section> 
 </>
);
}

export default LoadMore;
```

`

[image]

useInView hook; The useInView hook makes it easy to monitor the inView state of your components. Call the useInView hook with the (optional) options you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hooks are not allowed in server components as they run only once and don't run on the client (where hooks are supposed to be executed).`useInview()`

So that means we have to convert our component to a client-side component by using it as a `"use client";`

```
 "use client";
 import Image from "next/image";
 import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";
```

The `use client` directive is a React API Reference Directive. It is needed only if you’re using React Server Components or building a library compatible with them.
`use client` lets you mark what code runs on the client.
You can add `use client` at the top of a file to mark the module and its transitive dependencies as client code.